# Issue with custom DataAnnotation

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

I have a problem with a custom DataAnnotation.

```
public class RequiredInt32 : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(value) == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult("custom-message");
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

I have that code. If the condition is met, no returns **"custom-message"** , returns me **"The field is invalid"**. For me return the message I want, I need to put it explicitly.

**[RequiredInt32 (ErrorMessage = @ "custom-message")]**

What I have wrong and how can I do to have a default message. Thank you!

Comment: You need to override `FormatErrorMessage` too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to customize formatting error message, you can define an attribute like this:

```
public class RequiredInt32 : ValidationAttribute
{
    private const string _customFormat = "{0} is not valid";

    private string _fieldName;

    public RequiredInt32(string fieldName)
        : base(_customFormat)
    {
        _fieldName = fieldName;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format(ErrorMessageString, name);
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(value) == 0)
            {
                return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(_fieldName));
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[RequiredInt32("MyField")]
public int NumberProperty {get;set;}
```